# Action works with POST, but not with GET (query string)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been using an Action for obtaining a report's data, as a JSON object, with no problems POSTing a form to it with jQuery's ajax.

But now I need to return different result types depending on a parameter's value. It should return either JSON, an Excel file (built with HTML) or a PDF file. So I have created a nested enum on my controller class for delimiting the available return types.

But now, when I try to invoke the Action from a URL for generating the files, it throws an `ArgumentException` with the message:

`` The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'dataInicio' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DadosRelatorioResumoLancamentos(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.String, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, TipoResultado)' in 'Imovelweb.Web.Intranet.Controllers.RelatoriosController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Parameter name: parameters ``

Still, the `dataInicio` parameter is present at the query string:

`http://localhost:32331/Relatorios/DadosRelatorioResumoLancamentos?codFantasia=106&numAp=&dataInicio=21%2F03%2F2012&dataFim=21%2F03%2F2012&tipoResultado=1`

I have tried the original request (wich returns JSON content) with both methods, and it works with POST, but not with GET (the same `ArgumentException` is thrown).

What am I missing?

Here is the Action method's signature:

```
public ActionResult DadosRelatorioResumoLancamentos(
    int? codFantasia, 
    string numAp, 
    DateTime dataInicio, 
    DateTime dataFim, 
    TipoResultado tipoResultado = TipoResultado.Json
);
```

And here is the enum:

```
public enum TipoResultado
{ 
    Json,
    Excel,
    Pdf
}
```

Comment: How does Route table looks like? It seems to me that MVC is calling incorrect action method - the one without dataInicio parameter?

Comment: @TomasVoracek The correct action was being called. The problem was the date format, as said in the answer by pjumble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem, the default ASP.NET MVC model binder parses QueryString values as `InvariantCulture`, whereas POSTed form values will get parsed using `CurrentCulture`.

This means in your GET request it will attempt to parse 21/03/2012 in the American format MM/dd/yyyy, which is invalid. Since your `dataInicio` parameter isn't nullable it won't be able to supply a suitable value so it'll throw an `ArgumentException`.

There's a full write-up / workaround here: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx